# HTTP request in Dialplan

Tags: freeswitch, fusionpbx

How would I go about preforming a HTTP GET request in the dialplan to send data to another system. I have done this in asterisks using curl. I have looked in freeswitch's mod folder and it doesn't have mod_curl. I am using a default install of FusionPBX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Debian 8 with the FreeSWITCH package you would run the following.

apt install freeswitch-mod-curl

Then go to the Menu -> Advanced -> Modules and make sure the module is setup to run automatically and make sure its started.

Then follow instructions found here.
https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_curl

Answer (score 0):

There actually is [mod_curl](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_curl), though not compiled by default. You may need to follow the steps to compile it yourself.

You have the option to use it directly in dialplan, or in lua script.